# Audio playing later than it should

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

[Unity 5.5.1f1] [C#]

I just made a reloading script which is supposed to play a sound as soon as it starts reloading.
The script works perfectly, but the sound starts playing exactly when it's DONE reloading.
Moving the line up outside of the current  if, to  under the  `if (currentClip <= 0 || pressedR == true)` doesn't work either.
Does someone know how to let the sound play as soon as the reloading starts? (preferably under `if (totalAmmo > 1)` so that it won't play when all reserve ammo is also depleted)

```
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && counter > DelayTime && reloading == false)                                                                   
    {
        Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation); //Spawning the bullet
        currentClip += -1;
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R)) //This will allow the player to use "R" to reload.
    {
        pressedR = true;
    }
    //Start of reloading
    if (currentClip <= 0 || pressedR == true)
    {
        reloading = true;
        if (totalAmmo > 1)
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();     // <-- AUDIO AUDIO AUDIO
            reloadCounter += Time.deltaTime;
            if (reloadCounter > reloadTime)
            {
                missingAmmo = clipSize - currentClip;
                if (totalAmmo >= missingAmmo)
                {
                    totalAmmo += currentClip;
                    totalAmmo += -clipSize;
                    currentClip = clipSize;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentClip += totalAmmo;
                    totalAmmo = 0;
                }
                reloading = false;
                pressedR = false;
                reloadCounter = 0;
                //End of reloading 

            }
        }
    }
    counter += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that the clip is being played every frame during your reloading process, which keeps restarting it until reloading is done. As a result, you can't heard the clip play out in its entirety until the very end, which is why it seems like the audio is only being played after the reloading process.

To solve this, you should call `AudioSource.Play()` outside of the reloading logic - preferably when you first trigger the reload to start. However, you currently have multiple entry points into the reloading process - either when the current clip is empty, or when <kbd>R</kbd> is pressed. I'd suggest moving both of those conditions into the same if condition, and setting a single flag to start the reloading if either is true. At that point, you can call `AudioSource.Play()`, so it will only be triggered once per reload:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && counter > DelayTime && reloading == false)                                                                   
    {
        // ...
    }

    // Start reloading if not already reloading and either R is pressed or clip is empty
    if (!reloading && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) || currentClip <= 0))
    {
        reloading = true;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }

    //Start of reloading
    if (reloading)
    {
        if (totalAmmo > 1)
        {
            reloadCounter += Time.deltaTime;
            if (reloadCounter > reloadTime)
            {
                missingAmmo = clipSize - currentClip;
                if (totalAmmo >= missingAmmo)
                {
                    totalAmmo += currentClip;
                    totalAmmo += -clipSize;
                    currentClip = clipSize;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentClip += totalAmmo;
                    totalAmmo = 0;
                }
                reloading = false;
                reloadCounter = 0;
                //End of reloading 
            }
        }
    }
    counter += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Note that I appropriated your `reloading` flag for my purposes, since prior to that it wasn't doing a whole lot. By doing this, I was able to eliminate `pressedR` from your code, saving on a bit of complexity.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The problem with this is though, that it would play a reloading sound even when there is no ammo left to reload with.

Comment: Technically it did work though, but only when I removed the other `GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play()`

Comment: Also: Now the sound isn't played when the gun reloads automatically ( when `if (currentClip <= 0` is met). I could make it manual reload only if necessary.

Comment: @RnRoger Yeah, sorry - I guess I wasn't clear that you should be removing the `Play()` from inside the reloading process, or it'll just keep happening. Let me adjust some things to address your multiple entry points into reloading.

Comment: After putting an `if` before the `Play()` to make sure it doesn't play the sound even when all reserve ammo is depleted, this works perfectly, thanks man!